# JXTable convertRowIndexToModel wrong result after sort?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable

I have a `JXTable` in which a model is a `List` of distinct objects. There is a problem when I try to map the view index to model index after sorting the view by the selected column header. Using this code,

```
int[] selecteds = getTableMember().getSelectedRows();
if (selecteds != null && selecteds.length > 0) {
    for (int row : selecteds) {
        int rr = getTableMember().convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            System.out.println(row+":"+rr);
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
11:240
12:328
13:1174
14:328
15:1174
```

I cannot understand why different view indexes map to the same model index?

**Solved problem**:
I called fireTableRowsUpdated right after modify per row so the selected index is not correct anymore.

Comment: hmm .. shouldn't happen. Please check if that's specific to JXTable (as opposed to core table). If so, you have detected a bug in JXTable (which you might consider to report in the SwingX issue tracker) A SSCCE demonstrating the problem would help, in all cases

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the objects in the `List` are in fact distinct. In particular, the [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) used by [`DefaultRowSorter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html) must be implemented correctly. Note that the default relies on the `toString()` method of the underlying objects, but you can specify your own implementation.

Comment: That object's class is generated by `Thrift` and I'm pretty sure there's an unique value on `id` field to guarantee toString() will show an unique value.

Comment: Verify that `getColumnClass()` returns `Thrift.class` for its column and that the type of `id` implements `Comparable`.

Comment: yep, getColumnClass() return correspond Thrift-class field type, `id` column is typeof `String`.